# commons-digester fails to load my class when deploying in glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, classnotfoundexception, xerces, apache-commons-digester

I recently faced the below issue:

1) My application is an enterprise application. It is built on JAVA 1.5. Deployed in glassfish 2.1 and it is working fine.

Now we find it necessary to migrate from JAVA 1.5 to JAVA 1.6 and also from GLASSFISH 2.1 to GLASSFISH 3.1.2.

Now, when trying this migration problem arises.
During our application startup, using commons-digester we parse an XML config file and save it to an object. With glassfish 2.1, in both JAVA 1.5 and JAVA 1.6 digester parsing is happening fine.

But when doing the same in glassfish 3.1.2, we are getting the following error during application startup:

The following log file is from application log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ge.ifm.valueObjects.ConfVO
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:200)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1273)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1605)
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:87)
```

The following log from glassfish server log:

```
[#|2012-10-16T10:59:40.936+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException: SAXException-->Occured while calling parse of Digester Class.Exception Message is -->Error at (11, 7: ge.ifm.valueObjects.ConfVO
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    .
    .
Caused by: ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException: SAXException-->Occured while calling parse of Digester Class.Exception Message is -->Error at (11, 7: ge.ifm.valueObjects.ConfVO
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ge.ifm.valueObjects.ConfVO
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2540)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2566)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1605)
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:87)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ge.ifm.valueObjects.ConfVO
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:200)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1273)
    ... 77 more
```

We are facing this class not found error though the class exists in the build.

Kindly suggest on the same please....

Comment: Hi, this got resolved after modifying commons-digester source file.. Seems to be a commons-digester bug.. Modified Digester.java as follows:

Comment: public Digester()
  {
      System.out.println("Comes to 1 >> ");
      this.setUseContextClassLoader(true);
  }

  public Digester(SAXParser parser)
  {
    System.out.println("Comes to 2 >> ");
    this.setUseContextClassLoader(true);
    this.parser = parser;
  }

  public Digester(XMLReader reader)
  {
    System.out.println("Comes to 3 >> ");
    this.setUseContextClassLoader(true);
    this.reader = reader;

Comment: Is there a patch for commons-digester having above changes? Any help is highly appreciated !